# Need to get mean and max values with this script

Tags: python

I'm having a few problems.
First, given wind speeds seem to be low, especially compared to other weather stations reporting close by (apparently there are lots of enthusiasts in my area). Just watching the trees, flag, bushes, small animals flying across my yard, I can tell 1.6mph is a wee bit low. Everything tested fine inside, and when I run the test script outside its picking up the signal as it spins.

the 2nd problem is it *always* reports the "mean" and "max" speeds as exactly the same. I've tried to adjust the intervals, but no matter what length of time I put in, they always report as the same numbers.

```
from gpiozero import Button
import requests
import time
import math
import statistics
import database

wind_count = 0
radius_cm = 9.0
wind_interval = 5
ADJUSTMENT = 1.18
interval = 60
gust = 0

def spin():
    global wind_count
    wind_count = wind_count + 1

def calculate_speed(time_sec):
    global wind_count
    global gust
    circumference_cm = (2 * math.pi) * radius_cm
    rotations = wind_count / 2.0
    dist_cm = circumference_cm * rotations

    dist_km = (circumference_cm * rotations) / 100000

    dist_mi = dist_km * 0.621371
    mi_per_sec = dist_mi / time_sec
    mi_per_hour = mi_per_sec * 3600

    return mi_per_hour * ADJUSTMENT

def reset_wind():
    global wind_count
    wind_count = 0

def reset_gust():
    global gust
    gust = 0

wind_speed_sensor = Button(16)
wind_speed_sensor.when_activated = spin

while True:
    print("Starting Weather Sensor Read Loop...")
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time <= interval:
        print("Start timed loop...")
        wind_start_time = time.time()
        reset_wind()
        reset_gust()
        store_speeds = []
        time.sleep(wind_interval)
    final_speed = calculate_speed(wind_interval)
    store_speeds.append(final_speed)
    wind_gust_speed = (max(store_speeds))
    wind_speed = (statistics.mean(store_speeds))
    print(wind_average, wind_speed)
```

When I comment out "store_speeds = [ ]" the first loop the speeds are reported the same, every loop after I get a "max" reading thats "different" than the mean. This still troubles me, because why on the first loop are they the same? Am I wrong for thinking with the wind_interval set at 5, and the interval set to 60, that its taking 5 second samples over a 60 second period, giving me 12 sample to get the mean and max from?

My goal is every time it reports, I get a mean and max for that "loop" if possible, and not a mean/max over the time the script stays running before its interrupted/stopped.

Comment: `store_speeds` is repeatedly initialize in the `while time.time() - start_time <= interval:` loop, so the list is always empty when it terminates and exactly one speed will be appended to it in the following code. When the loop is entered again (because of the outer `while True` loop), it will reinitialize the list to empty if the *less time than `interval` has elapsed* — which seems wrong to me.

Comment: So it seems my concern has been validated in that its only saving one speed. Im very new with coding, so while I can spot a few things, this one has me stumped. I know there's something wrong, I just cant seem to figure out exactly what and how to fix it.

Comment: Questions like this are difficult to answer because I can't run your code (since I don't have the hardware). So — logically speaking — you'd want to create/initialize the list once *before* entering the inner loop and then append several speed measurements to it while executing it. Afterwards you'll then have multiple values in the list and can calculate the statistics from them.

Comment: When I remove the 'store_speeds[]' from the loop and move it under 'gust = 0' up top, i get the following:
2.089806956281316 2.089806956281316
1.7166271426596529 2.089806956281316
1.6419911799353202 2.089806956281316
1.9405350308326512 2.836166583524644
2.0002438010121173 2.836166583524644

I'm still getting same values for the first print, and then the same "max" until a new one is created. It still seems that this is only storing one value per print, and not resetting it. These values tell me the values being print are still the value over the time of the script not the current loop

Comment: What I need is, in the "loop", have the wind speed reported at a rate I can choose (i.e. give the value a name and list it up top with the others) to the list over another specified amount of time (again something i can change), have that then print the mean and max of that list, clear that list, and start over.

Comment: You need to reset `store_speeds` just before you enter the inner loop so you'll collect a fresh set of measurements for the next interval.

Comment: By placing store_speeds = [] above 'while time.time() - start_time <= wind_interval: (which is just before the start of the inner or second loop), i get the following values:
2.089806956281316 2.089806956281316
1.7166271426596529 2.089806956281316
1.6419911799353202 2.089806956281316
1.9405350308326512 2.836166583524644
2.0002438010121173 2.836166583524644

This clears the list at the beginning of the loop, which is perfect, but I still need it to collect more that one reading during that inner loop so I can get a true mean and max value report.

Comment: It *will* collect additional readings during the time `interval`. Sorry but this will be my last response.

Comment: What command do I use to have it run for set interval though?

Comment: That's what your inner while loop does.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working and corrected code:

```
from gpiozero import Button
import time
import math
import statistics

wind_count = 0
radius_cm = 9.0
wind_interval = 5
interval = 30
CM_IN_A_KM = 100000.0
SECS_IN_AN_HOUR = 3600
ADJUSTMENT = 1.18
store_speeds = []

def reset_wind():
    global wind_count
    wind_count = 0

def spin():
    global wind_count
    wind_count = wind_count + 1

def calculate_speed(time_sec):
    global wind_count
    circumference_cm = (2 * math.pi) * radius_cm
    rotations = wind_count / 2.0

    dist_km = (circumference_cm * rotations) / CM_IN_A_KM

    km_per_sec = dist_km / time_sec
    km_per_hour = km_per_sec * SECS_IN_AN_HOUR
    mi_per_hour = km_per_hour * 0.6214


    return mi_per_hour * ADJUSTMENT


wind_speed_sensor = Button(16)
wind_speed_sensor.when_pressed = spin

while True:
    store_speeds = []
    for _ in range (interval//wind_interval):
        reset_wind()
        #reset_gust()
        time.sleep(wind_interval)  # counter is spinning in background
        final_speed = calculate_speed(wind_interval)
        store_speeds.append(final_speed)
    

    wind_gust = max(store_speeds)
    wind_speed = statistics.mean(store_speeds)
    print(wind_speed, wind_gust)
```

Comment: Yep that's the logic I was trying to explain to you. Also watch out for those small critters flying across your yard next time you're out there. ;¬)

Comment: P.S. Glad to see you're following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) more closely, too.